# How to reactively expose the contents of a third party library?

Tags: vuejs3

Under Vue 3, when wrapping a third party library that maintains its own internal state, how can I reactively observe that state if it only exposes that state through a function call?

I've tried using `computed()` in the example below, but the computed function only gets executed once (presumably for initial render), then never again.

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="thing in things" :key="thing.id">{{ thing.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import ExampleLibrary from '@somethirdparty/example-library';

export default {
  setup() {
    const instance = ExampleLibrary();

    const things = computed(() => {
      // This computed function fires once, and never again.
      // How can I reactively expose the result of `instance.getThings()`?
      return instance.getThings();
    });

    return {
      things
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

All the Vue 3 `reactive()` and `computed()` examples I've been able to find are trivial ones that assume the state (or some derivative of it) is directly available as a local variable, rather than through a third party library whose contents I don't maintain.

(If it matters, the particular library I'm interacting with is [Uppy](https://uppy.io), and the function I want to observe the result of is [`getFiles`](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#getfiles). I tried to make the question generic, though, since it seems like it could apply to many situations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the library exposes its internal state (which it shouldn't), you cannot make the data itself reactive. I would assume that `getFiles()` returns a new array every time, not the internal reference, so something like `reactive(uppy.getFiles())` will not work.

The general approach is to wire the library similar as you wire a Vue component, except that where you pass data to a component using props, you use API functions with the library, and you use the library's events to retrieve updates.

With the files array from Uppy, you use the [`addFile()`](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#addfilefile) and [`removeFile()`](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#removefilefileid) methods to pass data to Uppy and use the events [files-added](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#files-added) and [file-removed](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#file-removed) to retrieve updates.

Here is the minimal setup:

```
const uppy = new Uppy().use(...)
const files = ref([])
uppyInstance.on('files-added', (addedFiles) => files.value.push(...addedFiles))
uppyInstance.on('file-removed', (removedFile) => files.value = files.value.filter(file => file !== removedFile))
// or just
uppyInstance.on('files-added', () => files.value = uppy.getFiles())
uppyInstance.on('file-removed', () => files.value = uppy.getFiles())
```

Now `files` will always be up to date with the Uppy instance. You can wrap this into a Vue component (or composable if don't need template code). Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

If you wanted to write a complete wrapper, you would use the same principle to expose the other events from Uppy and pass data to it. In the end, you could write something like:

```html
<uppy-drag-n-drop
  v-model="files"
  :note="Upload File"
  @onDragOver="..."
/>
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid managing my own copy of the state by using its methods, but if there's no other way, then that will have to suffice. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I know... But there are so many things that would go wrong, you'd never see the end of it.